# Why does Regex.Escape support number sign and whitespace?

Tags: .net, regex

It's my understanding that [Regex.Escape](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape?view=net-7.0) helps produce a regex pattern by automatically converting a pattern that contains regex meta characters to an "escaped" version of that pattern.

So if you want to match only `abc.abc` you cannot use that as a pattern because the period (or the dot) is a regex meta character that happens to be a wildcard.  Regex.Escape conveniently converts it to `abc\.abc` which can be used as a regex pattern that will not use the dot as a wildcard.

Regex.Escape "escapes" 14 characters...

> Escapes a minimal set of characters (, *, +, ?, |, {, [, (,), ^, $,
> ., #, and white space) by replacing them with their escape codes.

However, there seem to be only 12 characters that do not match themselves. Characters other than these *do* match themselves.

. $ ^ { [ ( | ) * + ? \

[This is the link to the reference that says there are 12 chars that do not match themselves.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-escapes-in-regular-expressions?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

The exact wording that makes that claim...

> Characters other than those listed in the Character or sequence column
> have no special meaning in regular expressions; they match themselves.

The difference is the last 2 characters mentioned in the documentation of Regex.Escape and they are whitespace and number sign. Why does Regex.Escape support more than the 12 characters that do not match themselves?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [free-spacing mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions#system-text-regularexpressions-regexoptions-ignorepatternwhitespace) (`RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace`), `#` and whitespace don't match themselves: `#` starts a comment and whitespace are ignored.

There's also this note at [the documentation page you linked to](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape):

> If a regular expression pattern includes either the number sign (#) or literal white-space characters, they must be escaped if input text is parsed with the **RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace** option enabled.

For example, this is exactly equivalent to `print\('Loremipsum'\)`:

```
(?x)
print\('Lorem ipsum'\)  (?#Inline comment)
 # Comment
```

...while this matches `"print('Lorem ipsum')\n # Comment"` (`\n` is an actual linebreak):

```
(?x)
print\('Lorem\ ipsum'\)  (?#Inline comment)\
\ \#\ Comment
```

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is that space and pound sign, if escaped in regex, work the same
in both ignore whitespace mode or not.

Left un-escaped, changes the meaning depending on the mode.

No regex manifesto is necessary for this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @InSync for making me aware of the `RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace` option. Also thanks to @sln.  Here is a longer answer.

The 12 meta chars in the documentation can be characterized as the normal meta chars. The reason Regex.Escape supports an additional 2 chars (the whitespace and the numberSign) is because when the pattern is defined using `RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace`, an additional 2 chars become meta chars.

In "normal" mode, that is without `RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace`, numberSign and whitespace are both literal, that is, they are not meta chars.

`RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace` lets you write self documenting patterns.
Specifically the option allows the introduction of whitespace that does not become part of the pattern and the introduction of a comment after the numberSign that does not become part of the pattern.
Effectively it turns whitespace into a pattern meta char that will be ignored.
Effectively it turns numberSign into a pattern meta char that will be ingored and all that follows will be ignored. We are introducing characters to be ignored because they are documentation.

Use of this option means you must escape whitespace in order for it to be literal.
Use of this option means you must escape numberSign in order for it to be literal.

```
Regex r;
        
r = new Regex("a a a #comment"); // in normal mode whitespace is literal and numberSign is literal
Debug.Assert(r.IsMatch("aaa") == false);
Debug.Assert(r.IsMatch("a a a #comment"));

// in normal mode escaping whitespace and escaping numberSign are needless but it has no harmful effect
// interpretation... escaping a meta char means make it literal
// in normal mode whitespace is not a meta char so the effect is to take a literal and make it literal which has no effect
// in normal mode numberSign is not a meta char so the effect is to take a literal and make it literal which has no effect
r = new Regex(Regex.Escape("a a a #comment"));
Debug.Assert(r.IsMatch("aaa") == false);
Debug.Assert(r.IsMatch("a a a #comment"));

r = new Regex("a a a #comment", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace); // the option renders the whitespace and comment insignificant
Debug.Assert(r.IsMatch("aaa"));
Debug.Assert(r.IsMatch("a a a #comment") == false);

// escape whitespace and escape numberSign by human coded escape sequences
r = new Regex(@"a\ a\ a\ \#comment", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
Debug.Assert(r.IsMatch("aaa") == false);
Debug.Assert(r.IsMatch("a a a #comment"));

// escape whitespace and escape numberSign by using Regex.Escape
r = new Regex(Regex.Escape("a a a #comment"), RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
Debug.Assert(r.IsMatch("aaa") == false);
Debug.Assert(r.IsMatch("a a a #comment"));
```

Aside... The option that enables 2 additional meta chars reminds me of the hyphen. The hyphen is not in the "normal" set of 12 meta chars but the hyphen becomes a meta char in the context of square brackets.

```
r = new Regex("a-z[P-R]");
```

The first hyphen is literal, the second hyphen defines a group from which the pattern matches to exactly one char.